# drawing from multiple urns based on a random number

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

Suppose I have $N$ numbered urns, each with different colored balls.

Now I have some fixed discrete distribution that I use to draw a random number $i \in \{1 ... N\}$.

I now pick a ball from urn $i$, without replacement.

Suppose that the first urn has orange balls that I care about getting. What is the probability that I get $k$ orange balls in $n$ draws? A draw being the two-step process of choosing an urn, then drawing a ball from that urn without replacement. Note that once a ball is drawn from any urn, it is thrown away.

We can assume that there are $v$ orange balls, and $u$ balls of other colors in the first urn.